# Return Problems

Tags: jquery

I do not know English very well;
The code below does not return value. return output; undefined..

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.mubsisUpload = function(options){
        var defaults = {            
            Tabs: false,
        }           
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        $.each(options.Tabs,function(i, name) {
            return name.divId
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    var event = $().mubsisUpload({
        Tabs : [
            {divId  : 'j123j4j3j212emas'},
            {divId  : 'dqwd123432dd8asx'}
               ]
    });     
    alert(event)
});
```

Comment: What do you think it should return? Note that the only return statement you have is in the anonymous function supplied as the callback to `each`.  You don't have a return statement in the plugin function at all, but it's hard to tell you how to fix it if we don't know what you expect it to return.  Normally I'd expect it to return the same jQuery or nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` there returns from the anonymous function inside `$.each()`. It doesn't return from the outer function. You probably want something like this:

```
var returnValue = [];
$.each(options.Tabs,function(i, name) {
    returnValue.push( name.divId );
});
return returnValue;
```